# Wiremock not templating request path segments

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone, handlebars.java

I am trying to use the `request.pathSegments` to render some information in a response and that placeholder is empty...

using 2.26

**Wiremock standalone start up cmd:**

java -jar ./wiremock.jar --root-dir "/usr/share/wiremock" --verbose --local-response-templating

**Stub definition:**

```
{
  "mappings": [
    {
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "urlPathPattern": "/v2/path/data/.*"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "bodyFileName": "responses/data.json",
        "transformers": ["response-template"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**template located in __files/responses/data.json:**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "{{request.pathSegments.[3]}}",
      "type": "values"
    },
    {
      "id": "{{request.pathSegments.[3]}}",
      "type": "values"
    }
  ]
}
```

**call to `http://localhost:8000/v2/path/data/foo`**

expected:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "foo",
      "type": "values"
    },
    {
      "id": "foo",
      "type": "values"
    }
  ]
}
```

actual:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "",
      "type": "values"
    },
    {
      "id": "",
      "type": "values"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried using `{{request.path}}` in teh template and that **IS** rendered correctly.

If anyone can spot what I'm missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using triple handlebars and `path` instead of `pathSegments`.

```
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "{{{request.path.[3]}}}",
      "type": "values"
    },
    {
      "id": "{{{request.path.[3]}}}",
      "type": "values"
    }
  ]
}
```

I find the documentation on this somewhat vague, and I usually default to triple, and then try double if the triple doesn't work. I also avoid using `pathSegments` when possible.